# How to filter rows `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` to a single row `(a,b)` in SQL-result?

Tags: mysql

How to filter rows `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` to a single row `(a,b)` in SQL-result?

In SQL I join a table with itself and extract all rows for which the primary key match and some other attribute don't match.

The result is that every row is "duplicated" in result. How do I filter these as described above ?

```
SELECT t1.courseId, t1.teacherId, t2.teacherId
FROM Gives AS t1 INNER JOIN Gives AS t2 ON t1.courseId = t2.courseId AND t1.teacherName <> t2.teacherName
```

Gives result:

```
dIntProg mch jat
dIntProg jat mch
dDbb ira sch
dDbb sch ira
```

Comment: please put here some sample data with output result and Specify only 1 SQL tag

Comment: Done as you requested.

Comment: Instead of using `<>` just use `>` or `<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
SELECT t1.courseId, t1.teacherId, t2.teacherId
FROM Gives AS t1 INNER JOIN Gives AS t2 
ON t1.courseId = t2.courseId 
AND t1.teacherName < t2.teacherName
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed. It removed all "duplicates" ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have to use `GROUP BY` to eliminate duplicates and use aggregate functions on all fields that are not part of the `GROUP BY` criteria.

For instance:

```
SELECT name, SUM(myCount) 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY name
```